# How to make footer stick at the bottom of web page in html

Tags: html, position, footer

My css for footer

```
.my_footer {
    background-color:#00FFFF;
    height: 60px;
}

.my_footer p {
    padding-top:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-color:#191970;
}
```

On my first page of html, footer position is at the bottom which is normal. But when I go to the next pages, the position of the footer changes. I have tried `fixed-bottom`, but that is nothing works for me

My `footer.html`:

```
<footer>
    <div class=" footer navbar-fixed-bottom my_footer">
        <p class="text-center">&copy; A&A shop pvt ltd.All rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your footer to fixed at bottom then

```
element{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

or if you want your footer to fixed at bottom and also stay at bottom on scroll then

```
element{
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: these codes are not working

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:**

USING FLEXBOX

Give the body (or whatever you have as a container of the page) a **display:flex** and **flex-direction:column** so they go under each other, then give it **margin-top:auto** or **justify-self:flex-end**, both of these works perfectly for me.

```
body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
footer {
    margin-top:auto;
    /*OR*/
    justify-self:flex-end;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

USING POSITION ABSOLUTE

The second solution is with **position:absolute**

[Live Preview](https://codepen.io/Mr-montasir/pen/qByBrKm)

```
footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: these codes are not working

Comment: I updated it, this time i'm sure it will work :)

Comment: i have applied every code but i dont see any changes. do you think there is a problem in css

Comment: I'm not sure, I think if you attached a codepen it will be great.

Comment: Have a look here: https://codepen.io/Mr-montasir/pen/qByBrKm

Comment: Also try to add `html,body {min-height:100vh}` This also may cause that the footer does not goes to the bottom of the page.

Comment: why the first page shows like this

Comment: I checked that link but it asks me to request access and I did, you received something?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XufLqRCU8J5hvWFy1uTxqjZR7c-Ik4QJ/view?usp=share_link

Comment: You need to make sure that the footer is not nested into any other div, and put it directly inside the body

Comment: you mean my footer.html is not correct?

Comment: What do you have in footer.html file? only the code you mentioned above or also something else?

Comment: i have the same code

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this CSS.

```
    .my_footer {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: these codes are not working